# Accidently shorted a TY72011P PWM, what are my options?

Tags: pwm

As far as I can tell the TY72011P (DIP8 package) PWM has been discontinued and I haven't been able to find a datasheet for it. It seems it's only possible to find the datasheet for a newer(?) variant TY72011AP2 which uses a DIP14 package.

Without the datasheet or local supply do I have any other options than purchasing the original TY72011P on Ebay (or old stock shipped from abroad)?

Comment: It's a PFM not PWM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This circuit dates back from 2001 so quite an old fellow but it was working very well. It is a quasi-resonant PWM controller featuring frequency foldback for good efficiency in standby power. See below an excerpt of the data-sheet and pinout:

[image]

The commercial version which is now discontinued was the NCP1205 whose data-sheet can be found [here](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp1205-d.pdf). You could potentially replace it by a more recent QR controller but you would need to a) change the aux. winding polarity which is in forward mode for the TY, and b) most likely have the opto reversed as most of the ICs have a pull-down regulation scheme while this one injects current in pin 3. Nothing insurmountable but a nice 3D-wiring project ahead. Good luck with the replacement.

Comment: I think I need to dig deep in my now 12 year old electronics engineering knowledge to switch to a more recent replacement (that's what working in a different field from your study does to you), but if I Ebay a TY72011P at least now I have a datasheet for further debugging, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

With all the patents, lawsuits, mergers, and acquisitions one can never be sure why onsemi (AKA MOT) obsoletes a good part except for profit margins.

You know that your choices are to deal with Chinese surplus disti's or replace the unit. There are no alternates, so the design must have had technical-cost tradeoff issues.  It was basically a current sensing hysteretic PFM with special signal conditioners for off-state offline.

But you can always pay more from *[local dealers](https://www.digikey.sg/en/products/detail/onsemi/NCP1205DR2/660700)* who buy from Rochester who in turn buy from Chinese *schlockers*.  But there will likely be a hefty premium or an MOQ.